# Sorting in ascending order not working Firebase

Tags: android, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hey I am trying to sort my data in ascending order but the data is getting displayed in the order of how they are stored in the database:

[image]

This is the function being used to sort the data to find the least time.

```
    private void getTimeTaken1(final String name) {
    final DatabaseReference databaseReference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
    final Query query = databaseReference1.orderByChild("timeTaken").limitToLast(10);

    Log.e(TAG, "getTimeTaken1: " + name);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int rank = 1;
            for (DataSnapshot userAnswerSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (yourTimeArraylist.size() < 10) {
                    if (userAnswerSnapshot.child("questions").child(name).hasChild("timeTaken")
                            && userAnswerSnapshot.child("questions").child(name).child("checkAnswerCorrect").getValue(String.class).equals("1")) {

                        Log.e("", "User " + " " + userAnswerSnapshot.child("questions").child(name).child("timeTaken").getValue().toString());


                        yourTimeArraylist.add(new PreviousDayRank(userAnswerSnapshot.child("random").getValue(String.class),
                                userAnswerSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class),
                                timetaken(userAnswerSnapshot.child("questions").child(name).child("timeTaken").getValue(Integer.class)),
                                rank));
                        Log.e("", "onDataChange: user" + userAnswerSnapshot.child("questions").child(name).child("timeTaken").getValue());
                        rank++;

                    } else {
                        yourTimeArraylist.add(new PreviousDayRank(userAnswerSnapshot.child("random").getValue(String.class), userAnswerSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class), "-", rankl̥));

                        rank++;
                    }

                }

            }

            query.removeEventListener(this);
            databaseReference1.removeEventListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `DatabaseReference` is wrong. Please use this code:

```
final DatabaseReference databaseReference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userId).child("questions").child(questionNumber);
final Query query = databaseReference1.orderByChild("timeTaken").limitToLast(10);
```

Where `userId` and `questionNumber` are the id's generated by `push()` method and the second by you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I guess this would just loop through` a single user and not all of them . I need to check all the users at a specific question id

Comment: No, it will loop trough all users beacause `userId` is a `variable`. If you have used for example in stead of `userId` -> `bpp2GTcF...` you would just loop through` a single user.

Comment: is the userId node a firebase reference ?

Comment: Yes, it is a reference.

Comment: Then I will have to use " " around it to refer to it??

Comment: No, you need to use the id that is returned by the `push()` method. So first you need to create the id with that `push()` method, than you need to store into a variable like this: `String userId = yourRef.getKey();` and than use in your `DatabaseReference` as explained above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142173/discussion-between-saransh-agarwal-and-alex-m).